# Can automated PDF reports based on template be made in Plotly Dash or R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly-dash

I work for a company that runs market research surveys for clients. Hundreds of different clients participate in each survey, so they do not all get an individual report. Instead, we have a report template in PowerPoint which is the same for all clients, and then we use a program called E-Tabs Enterprise to populate the template for each client with that client's own survey results.

These reports are typically about 100 slides long, and contain a mixture of static text and images, which are the same for all clients, and survey results, which vary between different clients. The reports are sent as a PowerPoint or as a PDF to clients via an FTP.

To increase efficiency, I want to switch either to Python Plotly Dash or RStudio Shiny to create static PDF reports (although I will also be interested in making dashboards in the future). I am trying to see which, if either of these, has the capabilities I need. I am already competent at Python Pandas.

It is clear from the Shiny website (link here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/) that Shiny can make a report and export it as a static PDF. However, I have two questions:

1. Can the open-source version of Plotly Dash also be used to create a report and export it as a PDF?
2. Is it possible, within (open-source) Shiny or Dash, for the code to loop through the data for the different clients and export each as a separate PDF?
3. If this is not possible, could you please tell me what the limitations are and whether it is possible in the paid versions of the two programs?

Please let me know if my question is in any way unclear. I would also be open to recommendations for other software if there is something out there more suitable for what I need. Thank you for your help in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: Have a look at library([rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com)). You can use it along with shiny.

Comment: You could run a `bash` script on Linux to render multiple reports at once. I think there is no value in using shiny for this task. In this script you could also use a script to automaticly send you reports.

Comment: R Shiny is for interactive web apps--it's the wrong tool to be asking about. As the earlier comment suggests, Rmarkdown would probably be the best R solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I can see that RMarkdown has the capabilities I need. It seems that there is no good equivalent of RMarkdown in Python at present, unfortunately, so RMarkdown is the right tool to use.

Comment: Though you can use Python code inside your RMarkdown documents. It's not as fully featured, but the basics work.